# Django - Can I trust receiving the relative URI as exactly the same that is submited by the client?

Tags: python, django, rest

I want my clients to sign with HMAC every request made to my rest API. If they submit a GET to

```
/u/bobtables?offset=0&limit=25
```

and sign this string, can I trust `request.get_full_path()` to **always** be the same as the above and verify the signature? Does something along the way change the order of the query params?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more flexible if you used `request.GET.get()` to get the query parameters that you are looking for:

```
offset = request.GET.get('offset', None)
limit = request.GET.get('limit', None)
```

or get all the params as a dict:

```
request.GET.dict()
{'offset':'0', 'limit':'25'}
```